# Is the current page a descendant of a specific node id?

Tags: razor, umbraco

How do I check using a razor template in Umbraco to determine if the current page is a descendant of a specific node? I'll be using a case statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if those methods still work with the latest version of Umbraco, but with 4.7.1 and `DynamicNode` there use to be those methods:

```
@Model.AncestorOrSelf(string nodeTypeAlias)
@Model.AncestorOrSelf(int level)
@Model.AncestorOrSelf(Func<DynamicNode, bool> func)
```

and those Helper functions:

```
@Model.IsDescendant(DynamicNode[,valueIfTrue][,valueIfFalse])
@Model.IsDescendantOrSelf(DynamicNode[,valueIfTrue][,valueIfFalse])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using uComponents / uQuery from http://ucomponents.codeplex.com/ you can do something like:

```
var isChildOf = uQuery.GetCurrentNode().GetAncestorNodes().Where(n => n.NodeTypeAlias == "MyHomePage").First() != null;
```

(Note: I haven't tried this code, but have similar in production)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way of doing it would be to check the nodes Path property (I think @Model.Path should get it). This should contain either a comma separate string or an array of numbers (not sure which off the top of my head) of the path from the node back to the root of the site. You can check for your parent node in that property. Which would save on more expensive lookups of nodes using LINQ or uQuery.