# Umbraco 6 razor menu

Tags: razor, umbraco

Hi I want to add a class of "active" to my li, if it is active or if I am on a page under that. I have the following code

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<nav class="topNav">
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf(1).Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible() && x.IsDocumentType("Subfrontpage") || x.IsDocumentType("Procesguide")))
        {       
            <li>
                <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I think I can do something with this, but it gives an error

```
var isSelected = Model.Path.Contains(item.Id.ToString()) ? "active" : "";

            <li class="@Html.Raw(isSelected)">
                <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
            </li>
```

This is the error I get. Line 10.

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel' does not contain a definition for 'Path' and no extension method 'Path' accepting a first argument of type 'Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 8:         @foreach (var item in Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf(1).Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible() && x.IsDocumentType("Subfrontpage") || x.IsDocumentType("Procesguide")))
Line 9:         {       
Line 10:            var isSelected = Model.Path.Contains(item.Id.ToString()) ? "active" : "";
Line 11: 
Line 12: <li class="@Html.Raw(isSelected)">
```

I have now tried with this, but no lunk

```
<ul>        
        <li>
            <a href="@home.Url">@home.Name</a>
        </li>

        @foreach (var item in Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf(1).Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible() && x.IsDocumentType("Subfrontpage") || x.IsDocumentType("Procesguide")))
        {       


            var isSelected = item.IsDescendant(Model,"active", "");

            <li class="@Html.Raw(isSelected)">
                <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
            </li>

        }


    </ul>
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: I have added the error in the starttext

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok here is the solution. This is for typed, not dynamic cshtml.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = null;
    var home = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf(1);
}

<ul>    
    @*Render Home item*@

    @{ var homeActive = ""; }

    @if( home.Id == Model.Content.Id){
        homeActive = "active";
    }
    <li class="@homeActive">
        <a href="@home.Url">
            @home.Name               
        </a>
    </li>

    @*Render Home children*@    
    @foreach (var item in home.Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible()))
    {                       
        var active = "";

        if(home.Id != Model.Content.Id){ @* if NOT home *@
            if (item.Id == Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf(2).Id){ 
                @* if foreach id and currentpage ancestor id is equal  *@
                active = "active";
            }
        }          
        <li class="@active">                             
            <a href="@item.Url">
                @item.Name                   
            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var isSelected = item.IsDescendant(Model,"active", "");
```

Here is a list of the functions you can use:

```
@Model.AncestorOrSelf(string nodeTypeAlias)
@Model.AncestorOrSelf(int level)
@Model.AncestorOrSelf(Func<DynamicNode, bool> func)
```

and those Helper functions:

```
@Model.IsDescendant(DynamicNode[,valueIfTrue][,valueIfFalse])
@Model.IsDescendantOrSelf(DynamicNode[,valueIfTrue][,valueIfFalse])
```

Reference: [Is the current page a descendant of a specific node id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754328/is-the-current-page-a-descendant-of-a-specific-node-id)

The following is the default script for navigation produced by umbraco:

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

@*
    Macro to display child pages below the root page of a standard website.
    Also highlights the current active page/section in the navigation with
    the css class "current". 
*@


@{ 
    @*Get the root of the website *@
    var root = Model.AncestorOrSelf(1);
}

<ul>
    @foreach (var page in root.Children.Where("Visible"))
    { 
        <li class="@page.IsAncestorOrSelf(Model, "current", "")">
            <a href="@page.Url">@page.Name</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: I added the code snippet from the default script produced by the navigation script template.  http://screencast.com/t/EVJrGjM11yyj  This code works and adds the `current` class to the main navigation element if the current node us under it.  It should help you with what you are trying to do.

Comment: How would you write that in strongly typed ?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a menu myself and needed the `Home` page to be `active` also. Working with just the method `IsAncestorOrSelf` doesn't work for the homepage.

The piece of code I've created is this:

```
@{ 
    var root = Model.AncestorOrSelf(1);

    var homeClass = root.Id == Model.Id ? "active" : "";
}

<ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li class="@homeClass"><a href="/" >Home</a></li>
        @foreach (var page in root.Children.Where("Visible"))
    {
        <li class="@page.IsAncestorOrSelf(Model, "active", "")">
            <a href="@page.Url">@page.Name</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

This iterates through all children of the root node (1). To be able to discover if you are on the `Home` page, I'm checking the `Id`'s of the page and set the `active` class accordingly.